# decode content type: application/ale

Tags: http, https, http-headers, response, content-type

I'm trying to upload photos and videos to my server, from my phone to server, and trying to intercept requests.

When the post/upload request is sent, I get that the content type is: `application/ale`

Looked into this and found that "a text-based metadata exchange format used to transfer film, video, and audio data between systems".

However is there anyway that I can decrypt this, or run and see which video I'm uploading or photo?

[image]
This is the characters that I'm getting on the post info.

I tried to treat it as base64 and decode to image, but not working.

Comment: Does `ale` mean `Application Level Encryption`?  https://infoq.com/articles/ale-software-architects/ .

Comment: `application/ale` is not a [registered mimetype](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application), which makes it hard to help. `base64` is easy to recognize and this is clearly not it. It's also definitely not encrypted. I would suggest you save this to a file and run the `file [...]` command to see if your operating system recognizes something.

Comment: This seems to be more a reverse engineering than a software development question. What client and server is used to upload files?

Comment: @Evert yep tried it, it just print Data

Comment: @Robert my server, and a developer did it for me, the upload is from an android

Comment: If it is an app developed for you hopefully you should have the sources (unless you made the mistake to accept only binaries). Without source you could still decompile the Android app and look at the code that generates the request how it works.